# Updating published post/page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin which should update `post_title` and `post_content` of a post. Because of layout problems or other security stuff, I would love to create a new revision for the post and guide the user to the wordpress post details where it can be reviewed. After checking the changes, the user should be able to set this changes live. If the post is still in draft, it is not needed.

I am using `wp_update_post()` to update `post_title` and `post_content`. I also tried to set status to "draft" but then the published content is not online anymore.

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wp_insert_post() instead.

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $title,
  'post_content'  => $content,
  'post_type'   => 'revision',
  'post_status'   => 'inherit',
  'post_parent'   => $YOUR_POST_ID,
  //'post_name'     => $YOUR_POST_ID.'-autosave-'.uniqid()
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Is it possible to inform the user when opening the post, that there is a new revision to check? with your option, the revision is just saved in the revision history, but there is not alert / hint.

Comment: ah ... just added "post_name" ... this helped! perfect, thanks